# Not receiving message body/content using Java Mail API

Tags: java, api, email, jakarta-mail

I    have    below    code    for    sending    mail    using    Java    Mail    API    with    attachment    and    body    part    (message    part),    but    I    am    getting    only   the attachment,    not    the body    message.

Any    help    or    comments    will    be    appreciated.

```
public static void sendmail(String to, String from, String url,
        String port, final String username, final String password,
        String filename) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", url);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("HTML        mail    with    images");
        message.setContent("<h1>Hello    world</h1>", "text/html");
        message.setHeader("Content-ID", "<memememe>");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        System.out.println("file    attached    is    " + filename);
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        // messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID",Part.ATTACHMENT);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart, Part.INLINE);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent    message    successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("::::::Error    while    sending    mail...."
                + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `setContent()` twice. The second call replaces the content that was set in the first call.

Comment: then, how can i call message.setContent() once for sending mail attachment and text message ?

Answer (score 6):

You are calling `setContent()` twice. Only one `setContent()` will work - the last one.

In order to have more than one part in your message you need to set the content to a `MimeMultipart`. Well, you are doing that - but the multipart object does not include the part that's supposed to be the message body.

If you want a message that has a text and an attachment, you create a `MimeMultipart` (`multipart/mixed`, not `multipart/related` as you did).

Here are some examples of how to structure possible messages:

---

The simplest of all is text with a few attachments. For example, you want to send your CV to someone, So you write a few words of introduction and attach one or more document (cover letter, CV):

```
mime───multipart/mixed─┬─text
                       ├─attachment1
                       └─attachment2
```

Multipart/mixed (the default for a `MimeMultipart`) means that the e-mail agent will show the parts serially - one after the other.

- If the attachments' content-disposition is `inline`, and the e-mail agent is capable to show the given attachment type, then it will be shown inside the message itself - at its end.
- If the attachments' content-disposition is `attachment`, they will usually be shown as some sort of icons or links for saving the attachments.

---

If you want to send a pretty HTML message, it is customary to include both a plaintext version and an HTML version. This is so that the recipient may be able to read it even in an e-mail reader that doesn't support HTML. It's very helpful if the recipient might be visually-impaired. So, you need to use multipart/alternative:

```
mime───multipart/mixed─┬─multipart/alternative─┬─text/plain
                       │                       └─text/html
                       ├─attachment1
                       └─attachment2
```

So, again, the message content includes three parts, the body and the two attachments. But the body itself is a `MimeMultipart(alternative)`, and it contains the plaintext version and the HTML version. Remember to put the plaintext first, and the HTML second, as the convention is for the mail agent to pick the last alternative that it knows how to display.

The attachments are going to be displayed serially after the body, just like before.

---

Now let's look at a mail that doesn't have "attachments", but it does have images that are supposed to be embedded inside the HTML. In this case, the mail agent needs to know that the attachments are not just files sent over to the reader to be downloaded, but that it should display them in association with the HTML. So the correct mime type for that is `multipart/related`, to show that the parts are related. In this case, you also need to give them proper content IDs, and use those content IDs in the HTML. This is not part of the MIME standard, but it's how HTML mail is usually done these days.

As far as MIME is concerned, such a message will look like:

```
mime───multipart/alternative─┬─text/plain
                             └─multipart/related─┬─text/html
                                                 ├─embedded image 1
                                                 └─embedded image 2
```

This time we don't have attachments, so we can put the multipart/alternative as our top level content. It has the plaintext alternative first, like before, but the second alternative is itself a `MimeMultipart("related")`.

Inside it, you have the HTML part, and the two images. The HTML and its images must always be parts of the same multipart/related object.

---

Now, what if you wanted to attach your document to such a message, one that has HTML *and* images inside it? Then you would be using something like this:

```
mime───multipart/mixed─┬─multipart/alternative─┬─text/plain
                       │                       └─multipart/related─┬─text/html
                       │                                           ├─embedded image 1
                       │                                           └─embedded image 2
                       ├─attachment1
                       └─attachment2
```

So your top level object is multipart/mixed, allowing you to add attachments serially to your message. The message "body" (the first part of the multipart/mixed) is the complex structure of multipart/alternative with an embedded multipart/related. And then the other attachments follow that.

---

In summary:

- If the message has any structure that is more than just a plain text body, then its content has to be a `MimeMultipart` object of some kind.
- A `multipart/mixed` message has a first part which is supposed to be your readable message, and the rest are attachments.
- A `multipart/alternative` message gives different display alternatives of the same content, ordered from most common denominator to most rare presentation type (e.g. plain text→HTML→rich text→proprietary formatting) and the recipient's mail program picks the last one that it knows how to display.
- A `multipart/related` message is usually used to combine an HTML body with its inline messages. The first part is the HTML, the other parts have Content-IDs that the HTML uses for its `<img src="..." />` tags.

Comment: sorry for late reply, but can you can tell me what exactly missing in my code to attach document & a message, i am not an expert in java ..!

Comment: i have modified program and i am using MimeMultipart("mixed"), but i am getting mail attachment  (not file), attached mail contains file attachment, cant we send file attachment+text ?

Comment: @mateen Did you follow the instructions? Did you add two parts to the multipart, one being the body and the other the attachment?

Comment: i have found solution for this http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java & thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the complete code to send automation test report with body text and attachment(Latest report attached) below.

```
public static void sendMail() throws NoSuchProviderException {

    Properties prop = System.getProperties();

    prop.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", hostName);
    prop.setProperty("mail.user", uName);
    prop.setProperty("mail.password", password);
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", portNo);
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    // Setup mail server
    Authenticator auth = new PopupAuthenticator();

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, auth);
    try {
        // session.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddr));

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toAddr));

        message.setSubject("Automation Execution Results_" + Utility.systemTimeStamp());

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        BodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        String filename = "AutomationTestReport.html";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(getTheNewestFile(filePath, ".html"));
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setText("Hi All" + "\n\n" + "Please find the automation test results" + "\n\n" + "Regards,"
                + "\n" + "Testing team");
        attachmentPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        // session.setDebug(true);
        message.setContent(multipart);

        transport.connect();
        Transport.send(message);
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Email report sent successfully....");
        Logs.Ulog("Email report sent successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Email report sent failed...." + e.getMessage());
        Logs.Ulog("Email report sent failed...." + e.getMessage());

    }

}

static class PopupAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(uName, password);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the newest file for a reports location
 * 
 * @param filePath
 * @param ext
 * @return
 */
public static File getTheNewestFile(String filePath, String ext) {
    File theNewestFile = null;
    File dir = new File(filePath);
    FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("AutomationReport_*" + ext);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

    if (files.length > 0) {
        /** The newest file comes first **/
        Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
        theNewestFile = files[0];
        System.out.println(theNewestFile.getName());
    }

    return theNewestFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add messageBodyPart before attachmentPart

```
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

message.setContent(multipart);
```

Otherwise you are getting the body message as an attachment